# How other party can access my contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am running private ethereum blockchain. As we know smart contract is used for agreements between non-trusting parties. Now, I am wondering how the other party can access/see my smart contract?

Like on etherscan we can verify the smart contracts using this [link](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract) https://etherscan.io/verifyContract and then we will get contract tab and user can see the smart contract abi and other stuff see the [link](https://etherscan.io/address/0x31cc5a0b2ea4c8e2061fe9c79e6c39942aa7e8f2#code)

Do we have similar UI for ethereum private blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is your private blockchain you control access to it. Depending on your settings you either have to allow others to run their nodes on the blockchain or for others to use your node. Or you can simply publish a website which states "my private blockchain has this kind of data" - others might believe the website or they might not.

So unless you give access to the blockchain for others (or they trust your word about its contents) there is no way for others to know the contents nor what smart contracts there are. But just knowing about the contracts is of course not enough - they probably need to be able to interact with the contracts so they need some sort of access to the actual blockchain.

If you want you can probably use some existing website framework for displaying blockchain information - I just don't know which frameworks offer their code open source.